# Chrome extension running slower when tab not focused

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Recently I created Google Chrome extension with page_action. The problem is that extension is running slower when specific page is not focused in Chrome.

Is there any way to change it's priority to run always like the page is focused? Or maybe to disable lowering extensions' priority in Chrome?

Comment: Removing setTimeout function from code fixes problem. But it can't be permanent solution as that timeout should be adjusted by user.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Event Pages and Background Pages in the Chrome extensions documents.

> [Event pages](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html) are loaded only when they are needed. When the event page is not actively doing something, it is unloaded, freeing memory and other system resources.
>
> The [background page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html) is an HTML page that runs in the extension process. It exists for the lifetime of your extension, and only one instance of it at a time is active.

It is recommended for your extension to use an event page, but it depends on what exactly it is you want to do.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to transfer my code from page_action to background. Looks like Chrome is limiting page_action scripts timeout to min 1000ms.

Comment: Actually it didn't yet. I will have to do more research and learning to fix this. Thank you for your time!